# node-trello: PUT-Method update

Tags: javascript, node.js, trello

I am trying to update an existing card on my Trello-Board. I am using node.js and the node-trello library for that. Following method returns an 'invalid id' error. Even though I have tried it with the exact same ID through Postman, where it worked perfectly fine.

```
client.put("/1/cards/" + destinationID, trelloCard, function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
              console.log(data);
});
```

The trelloCard-parameter looks like this:

```
{"desc":"Ticket #107 updated again and again and again"}
```

Any ideas, what I am doing wrong?